# how to create a formula for average when all the values are non numeric sometimes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula for average as per the following condition:

D3 should return D2 if both result 1 and 2 are non-numeric values(text)

```
       A           B         C
1   Result 1    Result2     Average
2   1             2          1.5
3   <1            2          2
4   <             <1         #DIV/0!
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: There are no D3 and D2 in your example. Also, that #DIV/0 suggests that there is something in your cells - what?

Comment: Simple AVERAGE function will work since Excel calculates number without any problem even are in `TEXT format`. You are getting error `DIV/0!` because  both `A4` and `B4` has less than 1, which are `0` and `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(A1)),NOT(ISNUMBER(B1))),0,AVERAGE(A1,B1))
```

[image]

To do the same for a larger block of cells *(like A1:A100)*, use something like:

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:A100)=0,0,AVERAGE(A1:A100))
```

Answer (score 0):

*If you want single Formula to calculate AVERAGE of both Negative & Positive number then you may use this Array (CSE) Formula:*

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(A1:B1<>"",ABS(A1:B1)))}
```

[image]

*Finish the Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and adjust cell references also as needed.*